# Http Error 503 in asp.net because of global.asax file

Tags: asp.net, http, global-asax

I am using godaddy for my website hosting I have used around one year without any problem,
right now I have a Http Error 503.
please look at the attached image.

I am using this request to make the website login(session state online) not logout quickly.

I have added session timeout to the web.config and i have used timer in the website.
just the request in global.asax files work fine.

Many thanks for the help 
[global.asax file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R2Dj.png)

Comment: Please add the code as text not as image.

Comment: Do you have any more specific information about the error? And did you verify the site starts without the keepalive code?

Comment: static Thread keepAliveThread 

        static void KeepAlive()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
                req.GetResponse();
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(120000);

                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keepAliveThread.Start();
        }

Comment: dear  – Inertiaboogie  , I just got http error 503 because of code in global.asax file. thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

[From the GoDaddy community:](https://nl.godaddy.com/community/Building-and-Managing-a-Website/Service-Unavailable-503-Error/td-p/5504)

> 503 Service Unavailable errors are most often caused by either your website having met its maximum concurrent connection limit or if your hosting account consumes all of its available resources.

Presumably your thread uses up too many resources. Perhaps there is even a thread limit on your application, it may not be allowed to spawn new threads.

Comment: thanks for your answer dear , what is the solution dear?

Comment: You could look for alternative ways to keep the application alive, for example by running a scheduled task from your own machine or by looking at free website monitoring services such as Monitis, Uptime Robot or Pingdom.

Comment: It absolutely will. Then you can also control IIS settings and set the session time to a higher value, or run a scheduled task in the VPS that keeps your application alive. One of those would be better than running a thread inside your website, imho.

Comment: 503 error is not because you are using session state. It because your application pool stop working. Why this is happened? Maybe it was caused by your site utilize high resources on the server so the application pool often get recycled. Please stress test your application first